Is `(expression, lvalue) = rvalue` a valid assignment in C or C++? Why do some compilers accept/reject it?
Some time ago I stumbled upon the idea of how a C construct, such as (expr0, expr1, expr2), evaluates (see "What does the comma operator , do?" for more context).
I've started experimenting with this, especially inside of function-like macros, and recently found a code which is rejected by some compilers, while accepted by others. It looks similar to the following snippet:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {0};
    (1, arr[0]) = 30;  // <--- potentially (in)valid code
    printf("%d\n", arr[0]);
    return 0;
}

As you can see, in order for this to work, (1, arr[0]) must be evaluated to lvalue arr[0], otherwise assignment would NOT be possible. However, I'm not sure if said behavior is valid or not. It "makes sense" and I found a use for it, but I also see why compiler devs would reject it.
The code above is rejected by gcc, clang and msvc (note that msvc is primarily a C++ compiler, while gcc and clang are C front-ends):
$ gcc main.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:6:21: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
    6 |         (1, arr[0]) = 30;
      |                     ^

$ clang main.c -Wno-unused-value
main.c:6:14: error: expression is not assignable
    6 |         (1, arr[0]) = 30;
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
1 error generated.

$ cl main.c /nologo
main.c
main.c(6): error C2106: '=': left operand must be l-value

For comparison, g++, clang++ and tcc are fine with said code (note that tcc is a C compiler, while g++ and clang++ are C++ front-ends):
$ tcc main.c && ./a.out
30

$ g++ main.c && ./a.out
30

$ clang++ main.c -Wno-unused-value -Wno-deprecated && ./out
30

I also tried with some different command options, such as explicitly setting msvc to running in either /std:c++latest and /std:c99 modes, or by setting different -std for gcc/clang/g++/clang++ but it did not change anything.
At first, I thought it's a bug within tcc, since it's the only C compiler which does not reject the "faulty" code, but then I checked C++ front-ends and I'm not so sure about it any more. Especially since msvc rejects it unlike g++/clang++.

Is the code I just presented a valid C, or C++, or both/neither?
Are C/C++ standards describing what should happen here?
Which compilers are right/wrong here? (tcc and msvc seems very odd)

For reference, I'm on x86_64 Linux, using gcc/g++ 14.2.1, clang 18.1.8, msvc 19.40.33811 (running through wine), and tcc 0.9.28rc (mob@08a4c52d).

Re: "It 'makes sense' and I found a use for it": OK, I have to know: what use did you find for it??

@ruakh It was a generic implementation of dynamic array. I wanted to do some bound checking before returning the lvalue from function-like macro. Something like: #define ARR_AT(ARR, IDX) assert((ARR)._len > 0 && (IDX) < (ARR)._len), (ARR)._data[(IDX)]) so I could do: ARR_AT(arr, 0) = 30. Yea, I know it's messy, but I was just experimenting. It seems like a valid use-case though.

@sleeptightAnsiC -- there is no need for comma operator in your above example, the macro would work with semicolon

@sleeptightAnsiC, you have mismatched parenthesis in that macro there

@ikkachu yup, ( is missing at the begging. Here is full code with some notes: https://godbolt.org/z/hsvEsrd3h

@Gene what do you mean?

@Gene: If the macro expanded to multiple statements, if (foo) ARR_AT(arr, 0) = 30; would make the assert conditional, the assignment unconditional.  Except in an NDEBUG build, creating a heisenbug.  It would also prevent ARR_AT from being an operand to function calls like bar(1, 2, ARR_AT(arr, i)).

@Peter Cordes -- those are such bad uses, so the old recommendation "don't create evil macros" is the best advice

@Gene: What's wrong with indexing a container as an argument to a function?  This is exactly like indexing a std::vector with bounds-checking on, except in C with macros.  Except unfortunately this hack only works in C++, where we could do the same thing better with a template function or a standard container.  So in C the only recourse is a generic function, or a GNU C statement-expression using {assert();  (ARR)._data[IDX];}

There is no shame in using evil features while whole language is also evil  >:)

In C, the code is not valid. As N3096 6.5.17 says,

Then the right operand is evaluated; the result
has its type and value.129

Note 129 says:

A comma operator does not yield an lvalue.

So, it is a "non-lvalue" (i.e. r-value) and cannot be used as an l-value.
For C++, on the other hand, per [expr.comma]

The type and value of the result are the type and value of the right operand; the result is of the same value category as its right operand,

Since it's the same value category as the right operand, it would be an l-value and would be valid.

Note that your code compiles fine in MSVC as a C++ file. MSVC, or more specifically CL, will treat .c files as C, and .cpp files as C++ by default. See here where the left compiler is MSVC forced to compile as C code, and the right is MSVC compiling as C++

Also listed in [diff.expr]/4 as one of the intentional incompatible changes made by C++ (C++98) relative to C when it was standardized. Also has a nice example showing that this can change the semantics of a well-defined C program when compiled as C++.

@ChrisMM Re: "Note that your code compiles fine in MSVC as a C++ file" Ahhh, I see. Thank you. I thought setting /std:c++ would do the trick.

@sleeptightAnsiC, that just sets what standard to use. It doesn't tell it how to compile individual files.

@user17732522, thanks, I missed that.

@sleeptightAnsiC - There are options to override the file type, but they are /TC for C and /TP for C++. Usually a lot easier to change the extension.

@sleeptightAnsiC I doubt any better answer would ever show up. It has enough details and references. The best way to endorse is accepting the answer.

Are notes normative?

@dumbass, per the same standard "Footnotes are provided to emphasize consequences of the rules". I think ruakh's answer explains the C standard side of things a better than mine.

For C: according to N3096 (PDF), § 6.3.2.1 paragraph 2 (page 48):

Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, or the typeof operators, the unary & operator, the ++ operator, the -- operator, or the left operand of the . operator or an assignment operator, an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated object (and is no longer an lvalue); this is called lvalue conversion.

In your example, arr[0] is an operand of the , operator, so should lose its lvalue-ness; so tcc is wrong, and the other C compilers are correct.

Thanks. I'll check tcc mailing list and send them bug report soon.

Got this reported here: https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/tinycc-devel/2024-11/msg00006.html

Tcc is not wrong, it is just not strict enough and accepts this unambiguous expression as an extension, probably as an involuntary side effect :)

@chqrlie Why don't you concider it as a bug? Just like someone mentioned in one of the comment's, this can alter the behavior of the program, e.g. int arr[] = {0}; int val = sizeof (0, arr); in this case val will have a different value.

It would be a bug to behave differently than specified in the standard, but when the standard does not support a given construction, an implementation may define the behavior as an extension. Both gcc and clang do this for many other cases.

@chqrlie RE: "It would be a bug to behave differently than specified in the standard" - this is exactly what happens. It behaves differently than specified in the standard. Am I missing something here?

Your parenthesis is misplaced. (1,arr)[0] should work.

Actually... This answer is somehow useful to me (although it doesn't answer the question at all). Moving [0] outside of (..., ...) makes it possible to turn anything into lvalue which I haven't thought about. For example: when wrapping (funccall, pointer)[0] or *(funccall, pointer) with a macro. This would fix the exaple of ARR_AT(arr, 0) = 30 which I mentioned in one of the comments.  Unironically, noone sugested this. Thanks :)

@sleeptightAnsiC I guess nobody suggested this as a solution because you didn't ask about arrays/pointers specifically, and this trick only works for arrays/pointers.

@sleeptightAnsiC Oh, I see: the (...) expression is not an lavalue in C, but it desn't have to be -- xx[0] is an lvalue even if xx is not, cool! (As an aside, in C you could also revert the operands for the [] operator, i.e. (1,0)[arr] should work. Because indexing is defined as addition, and addition is commutative, indexing is commutative as well, with the expected, well-defined results. That makes it obvious that the left operand does not have to be an lvalue at all.)

@Peter-ReinstateMonica: "Ordinary" addition would work with operands of matching types, but adding pointers to other pointers doesn't work.

@supercat That is correct but also is not the case here.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica: The notion that pointer addition should be commutative because ordinary addition is commutative is a non-sequitur.  I've used assembly language dialects where it isn't, and nothing felt unnatural about them.

@supercat Well, to a degree it is an ex cathedra argument: K&R 2nd edition, p. 177 make that argument for the language they designed.

Btw, this is how tcc keeps l-valueness on ternary operator — it just converts a ? b : c to *(a ? &b : &c) if possible.
